# Golang app on elastic beanstalk seems to be receiving double encoded requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, go

I'm using `gorilla/mux` inside a Golang application to retrieve variables out of my routes, like so:

```golang
func main() {
  router := mux.NewRouter()
  router.HandleFunc("/items/{name}", itemHandler)
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
}

func itemHandler(w http.ResponsWriter, r *http.Request) {
  name := mux.Vars(r)["name"]
  fmt.Println("name is: ", name)
}
```

If I navigate to `/items/super%20duper` on my local VM the console output is `name is: super duper`, as I would expect. But when I run this on our Elastic Beanstalk instance and go to the same URL the console output is `name is: super%20duper`.

We tried changing the `proxy_pass` entry in the nginx config thinking maybe nginx was not passing the request URI exactly as received, but that had no effect.

If anyone else has seen the same issue I would love to know how you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `func QueryUnescape(s string) (string, error)` from "net/url" package:

[QueryUnescape](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#QueryUnescape):

> QueryUnescape does the inverse transformation of QueryEscape,
>   converting %AB into the byte 0xAB and '+' into ' ' (space). It returns
>   an error if any % is not followed by two hexadecimal digits.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    s, err := url.QueryUnescape("super%20duper")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s) // super duper
}
```

output:

```
super duper
```

Comment: That works but feels like a bandage rather than a solution. I'd be a lot happier addressing the root cause instead of having to tack on another line of code everywhere I grab variables out of the URL.